# Firebase Admin Nodejs cannot find module service_account.json

Tags: node.js, firebase, service, firebase-admin

I start my node with "node firebasedb.js". My firebasedb.js contains this code:

```
var admin = require("firebase-admin");

var serviceAccount = require("service_account.json");

// Initialize Firebase
var config = {
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
    apiKey: "<api key>",
    authDomain: "<auth domain>",
    databaseURL: "<database url>",
    storageBucket: "<storage bucket>",
};

admin.initializeApp(config);
```

When I run node, I am in the directory where the .json file exists.
But it says

```
Error: Cannot find module 'service_account.json'
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You are missing the relative portion of the required path. That is, you should doing something like this:

```
var serviceAccount = require("./service_account.json");
```

If it's not a relative path, `require` will be looking in `node_modules` for a module named `service_account.json`.

Comment: Even with ../service_account.json or with an absolute path, will cause an error. ./service_account,json works

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that the TypeScript compiler does not know about `json` files. You can tell the compiler about them by adding the following declaration to your typings file.

```
declare module "*.json" {
  const value: any;
  export default value;
}
```

You can then import json with:

```
import * as serviceAccount from './service-key.json';
```

If you do not already have a typings file setup you will need to create one and then tell `tsconfig.json` about it by adding it to `include` or `files`:

```
  "include": [
    "./index.d.ts"
  ],
```

Comment: Thank you! could you please give more info about the typings file?

Comment: where is the typing file? which?